# How to reset authentication-service user initial keypassword

Tags: aem, saml

Am trying to setup SAML, and i want to reset the keypassword for the `authentication-service` user. Will it be possible by UI or any Felix Configuration?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by reset? Have you forgotten the original password?

Answer (score 0):

If you have forgotten the original password you are in deep trouble. There is no way to retrieve this password (to my knowledge).

The easiest approach here would be to delete the KeyStore under /home/users/system/authentication-service/keystore and set it up again.

Comment: Another approach can be to take the `keystorePassword` property from `/home/users/system/authentication-service/keystore` node and use [CryptoSupport.unprotect(String)](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/crypto/CryptoSupport.html#unprotect(java.lang.String)) API in a program to get the original password.